# Does the VS Code documentation for Python really mean you shouldn't open a virtual environment as a workspace?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

The VS Code documentation for [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) prominently includes this warning:

> Note: While it's possible to open a virtual environment folder as a workspace, doing so is not recommended and might cause issues with using the Python extension.

What can this warning possibly mean? **UPDATE**: I guess it means what it says; see my answer to my own question. I would rewrite the warning this way:

> Note: Your Python virtual environment should always be **a subdirectory within a VS Code workspace**. Opening the virtual-environment folder directly, as the root of the workspace, might cause problems.

---

[*Original question, continued*]

As I understand it, and [according to VS Code's explanation of what a "Workspace" is](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces), opening a root folder is the equivalent of opening a "workspace" (per the docs: "In most cases, you will have a single folder opened as the workspace...."). Does it *really* mean that we are we supposed to work in a virtual environment *without* "open[ing] a virtual environment folder as a workspace"? This strikes me as a completely ordinary workflow. The alternative—adding a virtual environment as a subdirectory within a workspace—seems pointlessly complicated.

For instance, say I have a virtual environment called `newvenv`, and I want to work in it. I might open VS Code by navigating to the `newvenv` folder in my shell and entering `code .`, or by using the VS Code GUI, doing *File→Open Folder→newvenv*. In either case, I get a workspace with the virtual environment folder as its root, as pictured at the bottom of this post. Yet the VS Code instructions seem to warn against this.

My only guess is that the warning *might mean*, "Don't open a **subfolder** within a virtual environment as a workspace." I tried doing this and didn't get any obvious errors, and I don't even know why one would ever *want* to do this, so it's hard for me to see why this would merit a prominent warning. But I would prefer not to just *guess* about the warning's meaning.

*Why I care*: I'm working on my own blog post about using Python and VS Code, and I want to make sure my instructions are accurate. I plan to write something a little more in-depth than most of the tutorials one finds on the web.

---

[image: screenshot of VS Code showing virtual environment folder as workspace]

Comment: make the virtual environment a subdir of the workspace

Comment: Thanks for the comment @rioV8. I do understand that I *could* make the virtual environment a subdirectory of a workspace. But I am not sure that I have to do so. It seems that you are taking the warning literally. I am *not* taking it literally because it is hard for me to believe that, taken literally, it is accurate. I edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: do you put your Python project files in a subdir of the Python install directory. **NO**. Multiple projects use a Python install version and you can delete the Python install version and use a different one without interfering with your project files, and not talking about your problems with git. See a virt env as a Python install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: **Yes.**  I don't know *why* VS Code warns against opening a Python virtual environment as the root of your workspace—that is, I don't know what problems doing so might cause—but apparently the documentation means what it says. As I noted in the edited question, I would revise the VS Code documentation to say:

> Note: Your Python virtual environment should always be **a subdirectory within a VS Code workspace.** Opening the virtual-environment folder directly, as the root of the workspace, might cause problems.

I couldn't find any direct confirmation of this, but I consider it indirectly confirmed by the screenshots below, taken from a [video by Anthony Shaw on the VS Code Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-udPvjv8jyI). These show that [Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7402337/anthony-shaw) creates his virtual environment as a subdirectory of his workspace.

[image: VS Code terminal output showing directory structure]

[image: VS Code explorer showing project structure]

In short, your workspace for a Python project should look like this ([from another Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUGm1Lwc55s)):

[image]